# Can I replace the pencil and marker with ballpoint refills in the Lamy CP1 Tri Pen?

Tags: pens

I'm interested in the [Lamy CP1 Tri Pen](https://www.amazon.com.au/Lamy-CP1-Brushed-Stainless-Tri/dp/B000UTMME8), which is a multipen that comes with three pen types - black ballpoint (M 21), pencil (M 41), and orange marker (M 55).

Is it possible to swap out the pencil and orange marker with additional M 21 (or non-Lamy ballpoint) refills? I would prefer a mix of three ballpoint colours.

The [How To Refill video from Lamy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ML8E_aFmBiQ) doesn't provide many clues as the guide shows a sketch rather than the actual pen.

I also found a [similar question on Drop](https://drop.com/buy/lamy-tri-pen/talk/453773), but the response was inconclusive.

Comment: I think the pen necessarily has three different 'mouths', which are tied to its three functions. I'm sure someone would be able to customize the pen, but in my opinion that's more an engineering question than an arts and/or crafts question. I think you will have more success at [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @TurePålsson, thanks so much for checking! That's helpful to know. Lamy Logo Twin Pen also uses M 21 and M 41 refills, so I will assume that the attachment points are similar in the CP1. Another alternative is using different (e.g. Zebra) brand refills which is another idea discussed at the Drop link, but looks like I will find out by trial and error.

Answer (score 4):

It’s a different pen, but: I checked my Lamy Logo twin pen (pencil + ballpoint) and its attachment points are different for the pencil mechanism and the ballpoint cartridge, so switching them around would be a non-trivial operation, if at all possible.

(The attachment point for the ballpoint is a tube that the cartridge slides into, while the attachment point for the pencil mechanism is a rod that slides inside the pencil. And, having disassembled and re-assembled the pen to check this, I must say that the mechanics do not inspire confidence...)